# Indexing a multi-dimensional tensor using only one dimension

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

I have a PyTorch tensor `b` with the shape:  `torch.Size([10, 10, 51])`. I want to select one element between the 10 possible elements in the dimension d=1 (middle one) using a numpy array: `a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`. this is just a random example.

I wanted to do:
`b[:,a,:]` but that isn't working

Comment: So you expect back a tensor of shape `(10, 51)`?

Comment: @rkechols yes indeed

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what you're expecting to get back. Please provide a small example of `b` tensor and what tensor you're expecting to get out.

Comment: it's okay, thanks for your help. I posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is likely `torch.index_select` ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html))

You'll have to turn `a` into a tensor first, though.

```py
a_torch = torch.from_numpy(a)
answer = torch.index_select(b, 1, a_torch)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful

Comment: It didn't work. I got an array with the same size as ` b`

Answer (score 0):

An indexing of `b` on the second axis using `a` should do:

```
>>> b = torch.rand(10, 10, 51)
>>> a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

>>> b[:,  a].shape
torch.Size([10, 10, 51])
```

Comment: I am trying to select only one element from the second dimension. In your result, the output still has an output shape of  `[10, 10, 51]`, while I want one such as  `[10, 51]` @Ivan

Comment: I is not clear which element from the first axis you want to select, can you show a small example to illustrate the desired result?

Comment: I found the solution on the PyTorch forum. I will answer in a post. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on the PyTorch forum:
(https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-select-specific-vector-in-3d-tensor-beautifully/37724)

```
x = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]],
                  [[11, 12, 13],
                   [14, 15, 16],
                   [17, 18, 19]]])

idx = torch.tensor([1, 2])
x[torch.arange(x.size(0)), idx]
```